# Difficulty with connecting css to html django

Tags: html, css

There were problems connecting the css file to the project. If you specify styles inside the html file, through  - everything works well. But if you refer to a project style file, many styles simply refuse to work.

css file:

```
.imgsize{
    width: 350px;
    height:350px;
}
```

html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/tren.css' %}">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'image/h.png' %}">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="der">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="border border-success rounded bg-light text-dark">
      <div class="ml-1">
        <img class="imgsize" src="{% static 'image/1.jpg' %}" alt="Картинка"> //This does not work
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/alEe3.png

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I am trying to apply this style to an image. I tried to put !important; thinking that this is a bootstrap does not allow you to apply this style, but nothing happened. The style is not applied.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it